# Data not fetching after deleting one row in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've created todo app in laravel in which there's a delete button. Whenever I add data, it works, shows in the table. But after clicking delete button, other data are appearing not in table.

[image]

ToDosController

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $userid = $request->user()->todos()->get(['id']);
        $arr = ToDo::whereIn('user_id', $userid)->paginate(5);
        $count['counts'] = ToDo::whereIn('user_id', $userid);
        $pending = ToDo::where('status', 'Pending');
        $completed = ToDo::where('status', 'Completed');
        return view('admin.todo.index')->with('todos',$arr)->with($count)->with('pending',$pending)->with('completed',$completed)->with((array('user' => Auth::user())));
    }
 public function destroy($id) { 
   $todo = ToDo::find($id); 
   $todo->delete(); 
   return redirect()->route('admin.todo.index')->with('success', 'Deleted Successfully'); 
}
```

View

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Schedule</th>
                    <th>Deadline</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                @if(count($todos) > 0)
                @foreach($todos as $td)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @if($td->status == 'Pending')
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{ $td->status }}</span></td>
                            @elseif($td->status == 'Completed')
                            <span class="label label-success">{{ $td->status }}</span></td>
                            @endif
                            </td>
                        <td>{{ $td->title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $td->description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $td->schedule }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $td->deadline }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{route('admin.todo.edit',$td->id)}}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="$(this).parent().find('form').submit()" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            <a href="{{ route('admin.todo.show',$td->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Show</a>
                            <form action="{{route('admin.todo.destroy',$td->id)}}" method="post" value="DELETE">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            </form>
                            </td>

                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

You can see in image that it's showing pending todo, completed todo but it's not showing them in table.

Comment: Can you show the delete method and also the frontend javascript if its an ajax?

Comment: It's there's in <form> .

Here's destroy

`public function destroy($id)
    {
        $todo = ToDo::find($id);
        $todo->delete();
        return redirect()->route('admin.todo.index')->with('success', 'Deleted Successfully');
    }`

Comment: It's inside form, check last part of view.

Comment: I think you need to do a page refresh after delete ... this table looks pretty static for me

Comment: Page is refreshing but still not showing.

Comment: Problem is happining only when I'm deleting first row not other than first. If I'm deleting 4th rown then everything is working fine but when I'm deleting first row then it stop loading data from table even after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $completed = ToDo::where('status', 'Completed');
```

you're not even getting the data there, replace it with:-

```
 $completed = ToDo::where('status', 'Completed')->get();
```

and try to dump each variable after you get it and see if it's the expected data.

why use whereIN , while its just 1 value as userid meant to be unique value as foreign key of users table? just use where clause?

```
$arr = ToDo::where('user_id', '=', $userid)->paginate(5);
```

this should work.

Comment: I'm getting result for $completed but I'm not getting result for 
`@foreach($todos as $td)`

Comment: have you tried to dd($arr)?  why use whereIN , while its just 1 value as userid meant to be unique value as foreign key of users table? just use where clause?
$arr = ToDo::where('user_id', '=', $userid)->paginate(5);
tell me if u r getting results, try displaying it with just ToDo::where('user_id', '=', $userid)->get(); ?

Comment: Getting foreach error on adding = sign.
Here's dd.

`LengthAwarePaginator {#371 ▼`
`  #total: 0`
 ` #lastPage: 0`
 ` #items: Collection {#361 ▼`
 `   #items: []`
 ` }`
 ` #perPage: 5`
 ` #currentPage: 1`
 ` #path: "http://autocrats.balraj.co/admin/todo"`
 ` #query: []`
 ` #fragment: null`
`  #pageName: "page"`
`}`

Comment: Array is empty. Error on adding = sign:  (1/1) ErrorException

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by calling Auth::user and replacing whereIn by where.

```
$arr = (ToDo::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(5));
```